# What is the difference between get requests via XMLHttpRequest, curl, and browser URL in terms of CORS?

Tags: javascript, curl, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to wrap my head around CORS (cross origin resource sharing) by reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS. Here, I noticed that the document states:

> Cross-site HTTP requests initiated from within **scripts** have been subject to well-known restrictions, for well-understood security reasons.  For example HTTP Requests made using the XMLHttpRequest object were subject to the same-origin policy.

This makes sense to me, as I have experienced the following error before:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load `http://localhost:7000`. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin `http://localhost:9000` is therefore not allowed
>   access.

However, why does `curl http://localhost:7000` return the JSON that located on the page correctly? Is it simply the fact that `curl` commands don't come from scripts? In addition, how does the browser even recognize that the request is coming from a script? If this differentiates significantly from browser to browser, I'd be curious to know about how Chrome and Firefox detect this.

Comment: curl!=XMLHttpRequest , the MDN-article is related to clientside scripts

Answer (score 0):

In my idea 
 XMLHttpRequest is javascript call server to get data and noad reload page. No page load first no XMLHttpRequest.
 Curl is php server function get data from server and return to php code, curl is a part of server code.

Comment: this comment is hard to understand